# ResourceBundle Editor disables basic functions in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, internationalization, spring-tool-suite

I am working with Spring Tool Suite

- Version: 3.6.0.RELEASE
- Build Id: 201407101106
- Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)

and due i18n requirements I have installed [Eclipse ResourceBundle Editor](http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/)

- ResourceBundle Editor 1.0.3 com.essiembre.eclipse.rbe.feature.group Pascal Essiembre

The Plugin works perfect. But the IDE has a weird situation, once when in the project a .properties file is created and then it is handled by the ResourceBundle Editor, practically for any java class in the IDE, the "Ctrl + Space" stops to work, any autocomplete feature does not work anymore, any reference variable with the "dot" pressed, to let me see the list of methods, it does not work anymore too..

To resolve this I must restart the IDE… of course if I open again a .properties managed through this plugin all goes wrong again

Seems it is a bug, or perhaps I forget to do an extra configuration.

I already have reported this to them:
[ResourceBundle Editor disables basic functions in the IDE #12](https://github.com/essiembre/eclipse-rbe/issues/12)

Without any reply yet..

Exists a way or special setting to around this situation?

The error:

[image: ErrorLog Plugin]

Error stacktrace for **Unhandled event loop exception**

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3983)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4422)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBackground(Control.java:3479)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.createProposalSelector(CompletionProposalPopup.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$22(CompletionProposalPopup.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.showProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$2.run(ContentAssistant.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    ... 23 more
```

Update: `Second Update`

Just a clean or new Eclipse installation, practically from the scratch.

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600
```

Plugin installed, same sad history

**Message**:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
```

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3983)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4422)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBackground(Control.java:3479)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.createProposalSelector(CompletionProposalPopup.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$22(CompletionProposalPopup.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.showProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$2.run(ContentAssistant.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    ... 23 more
```

**Session Data**:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/manueljordan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/manueljordan/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

How Reproduce the error:

1. Have any project created
2. File -> New -> Other -> ResourceBundle -> ResourceBundle
3. Next and create the .properties file according with the requirements of i18n, Finish
4. Locate and select the main or default .properties file (i.e. messages.properties)
5. Right click -> Open With -> ResourceBundle Editor

Comment: Do you see anything in the Error Log? And if not, did you take a look at the Java -> Editor -> Content-Assist settings? Maybe something gets configured in a weird way.

Comment: `Do you see anything in the Error Log?` Where I should read that information? If is in the Console, nothing appears, in the STS directories I can't find a `log` directory. I did the steps to arrive into `Content Assist`, I took a picture before and after to open a .properties file with the plugin, and I see no differences. I am confused, some idea?

Comment: There is a view in Eclipse/STS that you can open that is called "Error Log" where problems that happen inside Eclipse/STS are logged. Would be interesting to see if something shows up inside that view (maybe including a stack trace for the problem mentioned above).

Comment: Funny, I have opened that view, a long list of errors has been listed, thinking in send a photo with only the *expected* error for presentation purposes, I have deleted the items of the list, I have opened a .properties file handled by the plugin and nothing appears in the *view*, I have edited the .properties file, saved it and the *view* remains empty... what is the funny? Now the classes are working how always, I can use the *autocomplete* feature and the *dot* behavior works now. If something changes I am going to share the image. Thank You.

Comment: Second Observation: The previous comment is true, after to compile the project, **just then**, errors message have been listed in the *view*, now all goes wrong how has been reported. An image has been attached in the post, open it in a new window to see it better

Comment: This looks like a content-assist bug in Eclipse, but I wonder why you are hitting this. Do you have a few steps how to reproduce this from a plain STS or Eclipse installation?

Comment: Hi Martin check `Second Update` same situation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this and it seems indeed a problem that happens when installing and using the ResourceBundleEditor in STS. The exception is not throwh when doing the exactly same thing in a plain Eclipse Luna Java EE distribution (after installing the ResourceBundleEditor). Therefore I opened: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3917 to investigate this issue.

Comment: Wondered why you have no the same bug in `Eclipse Luna JEE distribution `, because I have the same bug in `Eclipse Luna JEE distribution`, reported (added) in the first post, check the `Second Update` section.

Comment: if it happens in a plain Eclipse Luna version, you should report this to the ResourceBundleEditor authors, as you did.

Comment: It will be done, the problem is, my original issue has not been covered yet. There are no comments..

Comment: This is the problem in ResourceBundle Editor plugin. One of the UI components is disposing grey system color, which is being used by various Eclipse UI components and must not be disposed. I have created a PR for Eclipse-RBE on GitHub: https://github.com/essiembre/eclipse-rbe/pull/16 
This is not an STS issue, consequently needs to be tracked via the PR above.